# MS Build Failure on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am new to Jenkins CI. However the issue looks very easy enough but its not working for me. My source code is in GIT and i am using Git repository for that.
I am getting the error below.

Thanks in Advance.

Started by user abc
Building on master in workspace /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hello World

> git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
>   Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
>   git config remote.origin.url

Fetching upstream changes from

> git --version # timeout=10
>   using .gitcredentials to set credentials
>   git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git7943155421179786207.credentials # timeout=10
>   git fetch --tags --progress +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
>   git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
>   Checking out Revision 833228fa50173e7977b4d5ee86c1385b5c6494be (refs/remotes/origin/master)
>   git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f 833228fa50173e7977b4d5ee86c1385b5c6494be
>   git rev-list 833228fa50173e7977b4d5ee86c1385b5c6494be # timeout=10
>   Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
>   Executing the command msbuild.exe NimbusAutomation.sln from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hello World
>   [Hello World] $ msbuild.exe ABCAutomation.sln
>   **Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' changed build result to FAILURE
>   Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
>   Warning: this build has no associated authentication, so build permissions may be lacking, and downstream projects which cannot even be seen by an anonymous user will be silently skipped
>   Finished: FAILURE**

[image]

Comment: @Permian who is editing questions: thank you for taking the time to make the images appear directly in the posts. Please make sure to use the **exact same** link in your edit, otherwise there is ambiguity about what has changed.. I see that the new image is exactly like the previous, but it requires to open the 2 images to see that there is no difference.

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by not configuring a jobs authorization policy correctly.

Check either the downstream job to see its configuration, or go to

```
Manage Jenkins-> Configure Global Security -> Access Control for Builds -> Configure Build Authorizations in Project Configuration
```

And check the global settings.

After finding the parent settings, go to the project giving the error select the same configuration in the section that looks like :

[image]

If this still does not work, you might also need to make sure that the user has the adequate permissions if you are using matrix based security.

```
Manage Jenkins-> Configure Global Security -> Authorization
```

And in the authorization matrix make sure the necessary user has build permissions

See also

[Authorize project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Authorize+Project+plugin)

[How To Configure Access Control For Builds](https://cloudbees.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/209641937-How-to-configure-Access-Control-for-Builds)

Answer (score -1):

Thanks. I did all the advised settings above, it only resulted in Warning message to disappear, the build still fails. 
The build works fine on my local Command prompt when i pass - msbuild.exe NimbusAutomation.sln but still fails on jenkins...

Path To MSBuild.exe: msbuild.exe
Executing the command msbuild.exe msbuild.exe NimbusAutomation.sln NimbusAutomation.sln from /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Hello World
[Hello World] $ msbuild.exe msbuild.exe NimbusAutomation.sln NimbusAutomation.sln
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' changed build result to FAILURE
Build step 'Build a Visual Studio project or solution using MSBuild' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE

Comment: " Warning: this build has no associated authentication" has no impact on the build: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-22890. Your problem is this: $ msbuild.exe msbuild.exe NimbusAutomation.sln. Note there are two msbuild.exe.